# Getting 401 status while sending email using Gmail API in Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, xmlhttprequest, gmail-api

I am getting the raw data of the drafted from Gmail API "get" method and sending it using Gmail API "send" method.

```
'var url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages/id?
     format=raw&alt=json&access_token=' + token;
 url = url.replace("id", emailId);
 var x = new XMLHttpRequest();
 x.open('GET', url , true);
 x.send();
 x.onload = function() {
     var jsonRes = JSON.parse(x.response);
     sendEmail(jsonRes.raw);
 }


function sendEmail(raw) {
    if (raw) {
        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages/send?alt=json&access_token=' + token;
        params = "raw=" + raw;
        request.open('POST', url , true);
        request.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
        request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
        request.send(params);
        request.onload = function() {
            if (200 === request.status) {
                alert("Email sent successfully");
        }
    }
}`
```

I am getting 401 status.

If I am sending this raw data from [API page](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/send) itself, then it is sent successfully. Therefore the raw data is correct.

I am missing something while sending the email. Please help!

Comment: is `token` defined somewhere?

Comment: Yes, the token is a global variable.

Comment: are you authorizing in `getEmail` ? Seems like you get 401 (Unauthorized) because you haven't authorized

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for all responses.

I sent the email using the following code-

```
function sendEmail(raw) {
     if (raw) {
         var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
         var url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages/send';
         var params = JSON.stringify({'raw': raw});
         request.open('POST', url , true);
         request.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
         request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
         request.send(params);
         request.onload = function() {
             if (200 === request.status) {
                 alert("Email sent successfully");
             }
         }
    }
}
```

There were two mistakes I rectified-
1. The token was sent in URL as well as header. It should be sent only in header.
2. The param raw was sent as String but it should be sent as a JSON object.

Answer (score 0):

A 401 error means "invalid credentials", most likely because your token has expired or isn't valid.

The Google API explorer and [Google Javascript libraries](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/features/authentication) take care of the token for you (generally), but if you're calling the service endpoints directly with `XMLHttpRequest()`, you'll have to manage the token yourself.

If you want to go that route, here are the details you have to implement:  https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2

You can try things out in the "Oauth2 playground":  https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/

Comment: But my concern is when the token is working for the "get" purpose, then the same token should also work for "send" purpose.